# Python 2 Selecting a key with a value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I want to select a key using the value of it.

I know what the value is but I don't know what the key is. 
So lets say the value of the key I want to select is 15 (in my case both the value and the key are integers) and there are 6 different keys. I want to get the number(name) of the key that has a value of 15.

I don't know if this is possible, but if its not possible please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
keys = [key for key, value in d.items() if value == 15]
```

If you know that there is only one key for the value, use [next()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
key = next((key for key, value in d.items() if value == 15), None)
```

Comment: I think I implemented it incorrectly. This is the error I get:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXXXXX/PycharmProjects/XXXX/XXXX.py", line 22, in <module>
    key = next(key for key, value in fotoWaardes.items() if value == 15)
StopIteration`

Comment: @DavidWestern This means that there is no such element. I added a default value, so it returns `None` instead of raising an exception.

Comment: Is there a way to change key to a integer? I tried int() but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @DavidWestern it depends on the value of your actual key. What is it?

Comment: That changes every time, But it always is a one digit number.

Comment: If should work is the key you are trying to convert "looks like" an integer. But it could raises an error if you try to convert `None` for example.

Comment: But when I print it it has [] around it. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: @DavidWestern Yes, this is the problem, you can not convert a list to an int. You should try to convert the first element of this list, like `int(keys[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to iterate over the whole dictionary and extract all keys of matching value:

```
d = {15 : 15, 6 : 15, 7: 12}
keys = [] 
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if value == 15:
        keys.append(key)
```

`keys` should now be `[15,6]`

NOTE:

This only works for Python versions before 3